# Get all data between two delimiters - Bytes

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read data from serial comport RS232, The data from an external machine is received in pieces. A complete frame consist of a message with  [STX][DLE][..Message..][ETX][DLE]. A complete frame is sent every second.  I am able to gather all the data but now i need to find a way to split and form the frames eventually read the message between [STX][DLE].... in order for me to process it. Kindly please assist.

```
Dim PortDataByte As New List(Of Byte)()      


Private Sub CommReceive(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles COMPort.DataReceived

    Dim SerialPort1 As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)

    Dim dataLength As Integer = SerialPort1.BytesToRead

    Dim data(dataLength) As Byte

    Dim nbrDataRead As Integer = SerialPort1.Read(data, 0, dataLength)


    PortDataByte.AddRange(data)

 end sub
```

Comment: Convert bytes to string then `dataAsString.Split("."c)` will return array of frames between dots.

Comment: sorry i have edited the above question, it doesn't show the special characters. I read somewhere if i convert the bytes into string it might add unnecessary characters in between. that's the reason  i am trying to split byte array and try to manage the data as it is.